# How to get text and image embedding of same dimension using Huggingface CLIP

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, huggingface-transformers

I am using `TFCLIPTextModel` and `TFCLIPVisionModel` to get embedding of texts and images that I need for some downstream tasks. I want the embedding to share the same dimensional space as they do in CLIP. However, as the documentation of these two models suggests the `hidden_size` of `TFCLIPTextModel` is 512 while for `TFCLIPVisionModel` it is 768. So while I extract the last hidden state from these two models, I get embeddings of different dimensions. I am also aware of the `projection_dim` which is 512 for both these models, but I don't know how to extract the projected features.

Here is my code for the embedding extraction for image and texts.

```
def Image_Embedding_Generator(images, batch_size=32):
    model_name = "openai/clip-vit-base-patch32"
    model = TFCLIPVisionModel.from_pretrained(model_name)
    processor = CLIPProcessor.from_pretrained(model_name)

    if isinstance(images, (np.ndarray, tf.Tensor)):
        images = tf.unstack(images) if len(images.shape) == 4 else [images]
    elif isinstance(images, dict):
        images = [image for _, image in images.items()]

    # inputs = processor(images = images, return_tensors = "tf", padding = True, rescaling = False)
    
    # dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((inputs['pixel_values'], inputs['attention_mask']))
    # dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

    image_embeddings = []
    cls_embeddings = []

    pbar = trange(0, len(images), batch_size, desc = "Generating Image Embeddings")

    for i in range(0, len(images), batch_size):
        image_batch = images[i:i+batch_size]
        inputs = processor(images = image_batch, return_tensors = "tf", do_rescale = False)
        outputs = model(**inputs, output_hidden_states = True)
        print(outputs)
        batch_embeddings = outputs.last_hidden_state.numpy()  # Convert to numpy array
        print(batch_embeddings.shape)

        pooled_embeddings = tf.reduce_mean(batch_embeddings, axis = 1)

        image_embeddings.append(pooled_embeddings)
        cls_embeddings.append(outputs.pooler_output)
        pbar.update(batch_size)
    image_embeddings = np.concatenate(image_embeddings, axis=0)
    cls_embeddings = np.concatenate(cls_embeddings, axis=0)

    return cls_embeddings, image_embeddings


def Text_Embedding_Generator(texts, batch_size = 32):
    model_name = "openai/clip-vit-base-patch32"
    model = TFCLIPTextModel.from_pretrained(model_name)
    tokenizer = CLIPTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

    if isinstance(texts, str):
        texts = [texts]
    elif isinstance(texts, dict):
        texts = [text for _, text in texts.items()]
    elif isinstance(texts, Iterable):
        texts = texts

    inputs = tokenizer(text = texts, return_tensors = "tf", padding = "max_length", truncation = True, max_length = 256)

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((inputs['input_ids'], inputs['attention_mask']))
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

    text_embeddings = []
    cls_embeddings = []

    for batch in tqdm(dataset, desc = "Generating Text Embeddings"):
        batch_inputs = {'input_ids': batch[0], 'attention_mask': batch[1]}
        outputs = model(**batch_inputs)
        batch_embeddings = outputs.last_hidden_state.numpy()  # Convert to numpy array)

        attention_mask_expanded = tf.cast(batch_inputs['attention_mask'], dtype=tf.float32)[:, :, None]
        sum_embeddings = tf.reduce_sum(batch_embeddings * attention_mask_expanded, axis=1)
        sum_mask = tf.reduce_sum(attention_mask_expanded, axis=1)
        pooled_embeddings = sum_embeddings / sum_mask

        text_embeddings.append(pooled_embeddings)
        cls_embeddings.append(outputs.pooler_output)
    
    text_embeddings = np.concatenate(text_embeddings, axis=0)

    return cls_embeddings, text_embeddings
```

As said earlier the `cls_embeddings` and `text_embeddings` from `Text_Embedding_Generator` have shape `(batch_size, 512)` while those from `Image_Embedding_Generator` have shape `(batch_size, 768)`.

Is there a way to get these two embeddings to same dimensions without needing to train an extra layer on top of these embeddings?